# How to make telegram bot send message when added to group?

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I need to make some sort of a "welcome message" when my bot is added to group. I'm using telegram.ext

Answer (score 0):

```
def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')
def main():
  
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

try